# Trouble installing ROS Melodic on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 64-bit

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having problems installing ROS Melodic version on my Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 64-bit. I've followed the [instructions from ros.org for installation](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu), but this is what keeps happening:

First instruction:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

OK, no problem with that.

2nd:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

Result:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.S60mWkJIrq/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: chave 5523BAEEB01FA116: "ROS Builder <rosbuild@ros.org>" não mudada
gpg: Número total processado: 1
gpg:              não modificados: 1
```

Apparently OK (if any doubt with the translations, because some parts are in Portuguese, just ask, or you can translate from the Internet, they aren't any complicated expresisons).

3rd:

```
sudo apt update
```

That's where the issues start. I get this as a response:

```
Atingido:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Atingido:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Obter:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]        
Atingido:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And then, the following instructions are to install ROS Melodic (`sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full`)

And the result is:

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
E: Impossível encontrar o pacote ros-melodic-desktop-full`
```

(The last line says it's impossible to find the required package)

So, I've serached a lot for a solution, I've disabled PPAs, I'm using the recommended ROS Package for my Ubuntu, and I don't know what else to do.

I'm also a beginner on both Linux and ROS (and ROS forums, for that matter), so I'm apologizing in advance for any stupid mistake I may be making.

Thanks in advance for anyone who may be helping.

---

Edit 1: Alright, so here's what happens in every last suggestion:

I have added the deb files, then, after `sudo apt update`, I get:

```
Obter:1 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename InRelease
Ign:1 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename InRelease
Obter:2 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename Release
Err:2 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename Release
  Arquivo não encontrado - /home/repository/dists/SuiteCodename/Release (2: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente)
Atingido:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Atingido:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease        
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Atingido:7 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Atingido:8 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto                         
E: The repository 'file:/home/repository SuiteCodename Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

After choosing the "best server", when also, as I close "Software & Updates", I get an error message, as it fails to download repository information again, I get this message on `sudo apt update`:

```
Obter:1 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename InRelease
Ign:1 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename InRelease
Obter:2 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename Release
Err:2 file:/home/repository SuiteCodename Release
  Arquivo não encontrado - /home/repository/dists/SuiteCodename/Release (2: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente)
Ign:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Atingido:4 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Atingido:6 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                
Atingido:7 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Atingido:8 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto                         
E: The repository 'file:/home/repository SuiteCodename Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

Edit 2: After all the tipos regarding the issue on #q325039, I successfully changed the key to the server, even the ROS Melodic tutorial has changed it, but it's still not working. The response I'm getting now is this:

```
Atingido:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Atingido:2 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Atingido:4 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease 
Atingido:5 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Obter:3 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB] 
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] 
Obter:8 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Sources [244 kB] 
Obter:9 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse Sources [4.608 B]
Obter:10 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Sources [280 kB] 
Obter:11 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [658 kB]
Obter:12 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [544 kB] 
Obter:13 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [243 kB] 
Obter:14 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB] 
Obter:15 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66,7 kB] 
Obter:16 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [127 kB] 
Obter:17 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [956 kB] 
Obter:18 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [942 kB] 
Obter:19 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [282 kB] 
Obter:20 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [245 kB]
Obter:21 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [190 kB] 
Obter:22 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [410 kB] 
Obter:23 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6.792 B] 
Obter:24 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [6.644 B] 
Obter:25 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.464 B] 
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto                     
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

Edit 3:
After following the instructions on disabling proxy and returning to the unchanged configurations, I got this response when running `sudo apt update` for the first time:

```
Atingido:1 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Atingido:2 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease 
Atingido:3 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease    
Obter:4 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]  
Atingido:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Obter:6 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main Sources [114 kB]
Obter:7 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [327 kB]
Obter:8 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [430 kB]
Obter:9 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17,9 kB]
Obter:10 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [10,4 kB]
Obter:11 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [25,6 kB]
Obter:12 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [568 kB]
Obter:13 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [561 kB]
Obter:14 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [36,1 kB]
Obter:15 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16,4 kB]
Obter:16 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [99,2 kB]
Obter:17 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.460 B]
Baixados 2.296 kB em 8s (290 kB/s)                                           
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
6 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

After that, I ran the final (installation) command, but the response was the same as always (in the beginngin of the question it's written). I tried yet again running the entire installation procedure, but the response to all command returned to being the same as the last time.

---

Edit 4:

Response to the "cat" commands:

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted #Added by software-properties

deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-src http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties


deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb-src http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```

---

Edit 5:

Output of the `sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/ros-latest.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"` command:

```
 Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
 Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
 E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
 N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
 N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

Edit 6:

Commands from #q325039:

```
 Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Atingido:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Atingido:3 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
 Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release                        
       404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
  Obter:5 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]         
  Obter:6 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
  Obter:7 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
  Obter:8 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Sources [280 kB]
  Obter:9 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Sources [246 kB]
  Obter:10 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [658 kB]
  Obter:11 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [544 kB]
  Obter:12 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]
  Obter:13 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66,7 kB]
  Obter:14 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [127 kB]
  Obter:15 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [943 kB]
  Obter:16 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [958 kB]
  Obter:17 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [283 kB]
  Obter:18 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [245 kB]
  Obter:19 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [193 kB]
  Obter:20 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [413 kB]
  Obter:21 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.464 B]
  Obter:22 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe Sources [2.072 B]
  Obter:23 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [3.736 B]
  Obter:24 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages [3.740 B]
  Obter:25 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7.228 B]
  Obter:26 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main Sources [114 kB] 
  Obter:27 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Sources [147 kB]
  Obter:28 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [327 kB]
  Obter:29 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [429 kB]
  Obter:30 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17,9 kB]
  Obter:31 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [25,6 kB]
  Obter:32 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [561 kB]
  Obter:33 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [568 kB]
  Obter:34 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [36,2 kB]
  Obter:35 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16,4 kB]
  Obter:36 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [104 kB]
  Obter:37 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.460 B]
  Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto                                              
  E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
  N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Output from `apt-key list`:

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
pub   rsa4096 2019-05-30 [SC] [expira: 2021-05-29]
C1CF 6E31 E6BA DE88 68B1  72B4 F42E D6FB AB17 C654
uid           [ desconhecida] Open Robotics info@osrfoundation.org

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
       790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
 uid           [ desconhecida] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg

 pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
       8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
  uid           [ desconhecida] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
       F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ desconhecida] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

---

Edit 7:

Output from `wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release`:

```
 Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  --2019-06-22 07:22:25--  http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release
  Resolvendo packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 64.50.236.52, 64.50.233.100, 140.211.166.134, ...
  Conectando-se a packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|64.50.236.52|:80... conectado.
  A requisição HTTP foi enviada, aguardando resposta... 200 OK
  Tamanho: 3801 (3,7K)
   Salvando em: “Release.1”

   Release.1              100%[=======================================================================>]        3,71K  --.-KB/s    em 0s      

 2019-06-22 07:22:26 (78,8 MB/s) - “Release.1” salvo [3801/3801]
```

The parts in portuguese are only saying that it has solved the packages, connected, the HTTP recquisition was sent, the file was downloaded and saved. But, even though it had apparently downloaded, I try running the installationg commands, and it won't work, the `sudo apt update` results are the ones from edit 6, without "obter 5" until "obter 31", and it still doesn't find the package for installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324486/trouble-installing-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-bionic-18.04-64-bit/) by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-06-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-12**:
Can you check whether you're running into #q325039?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> gpg: chave 5523BAEEB01FA116: "ROS Builder <rosbuild@ros.org>" não mudada
> ```

From the `apt-key` output shown I'm pretty sure this is #q325039.

Update the key, undo any changes you made to your `sources.list` (and files under that directory) and run `sudo apt update` again.

---

Edit:

> After following the instructions on disabling proxy and returning to the unchanged configurations, I got this response when running `sudo apt update` for the first time:

> ```
> Atingido:1 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> ```

```
Atingido:2 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease 
Atingido:3 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease    
Obter:4 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]  
Atingido:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Obter:6 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main Sources [114 kB]
Obter:7 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [327 kB]
Obter:8 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [430 kB]
Obter:9 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17,9 kB]
Obter:10 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [10,4 kB]
Obter:11 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [25,6 kB]
Obter:12 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [568 kB]
Obter:13 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [561 kB]
Obter:14 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [36,1 kB]
Obter:15 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16,4 kB]
Obter:16 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [99,2 kB]
Obter:17 http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.460 B]
Baixados 2.296 kB em 8s (290 kB/s)                                           
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
6 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Where is the ROS package repository here?

Is `sft.if.usp.br` a ROS package mirror?

> After that, I ran the final (installation) command, but the response was the same as always (in the beginngin of the question it's written). I tried yet again running the entire installation procedure, but the response to all command returned to being the same as the last time.

From the last `apt update` output you show, no ROS package repository is configured on your system, so `apt` not being able to find `ros-melodic-desktop-full` would seem to be expected.

You still haven't shown us the output of

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

and

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

without that we cannot help you any further.

---

Edit 2:

It would appear that `apt` is not downloading the ROS repository indices. Without those it cannot know about any ROS packages, so the `apt install` error is expected.

As to *why* `apt` is not downloading the ROS package indices I can't say anything right now.

Try a `sudo apt clean` and then a `sudo apt update` to see if that changes anything.

Edit: note: this does not appear to be an issue with the key at this point. `apt` is really not even attempting to download the indices. Verifying the signatures is done at a later stage.

What is the output of:

```
sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/ros-latest.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"
```

---

Edit 3:

> Output of the `sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/ros-latest.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"` command:

> ```
> Ign:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> ```

```
 Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
 Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
 E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
 N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
 N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This would suggest there is still a problem with the keys.

Can you make sure you have successfully removed the old key and imported the new one? Refer to #q325039 again if you need the commands.

You could check whether the key is imported by running `apt-key list` and looking for the key with a `uid` of `Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>`.

Can you please also show us the output of both commands?

---

Edit 4: At this point it would be good to take a step back and check some basics.

Could you please create (if you don't already have one) an Ubuntu 18.04 install USB stick and boot from it.

Then follow the ROS Melodic installation instructions. They already use the new key, so no need to follow #q325039.

If `sudo apt update` does work on the USB booted OS, then I believe the issue is with your current install. I'll leave it to you to decide whether to reinstall or to keep trying to diagnose what is wrong with your current installation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-19**:
I've updated the key, but then, after`sudo apt update`, I still get the "release file" problems. I've added the response to the code in the original question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-20**:
Seeing as you've made quite a few changes to various related settings, can you please make sure that things are back to how they were?

What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` for instance?

What was the output when updating the key?

It still looks like the key has not been updated.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-20**:
This is the output of the updating key command:

`Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.UB4RUijhZn/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654

gpg: chave F42ED6FBAB17C654: "Open Robotics info@osrfoundation.org" não mudada

gpg: Número total processado: 1

gpg:              não modificados: 1
`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-20**:
can you please always just add such updates to your original question? Comments are not suited for such things.

And can you then include the output of the two `cat` commands?

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-20**:
I've reset thing to the way they were before, and also disabled proxy, following another comment's sugestion. The response changed slightly, I've updated it above. But still the response to the instaliing command was the same, and after I tried `sudo apt update` again, the response returned to the way it was before.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-20**:\

> the response returned to the way it was before.

I do not know what this means. There are too many edits, comments and alternative answers here for me to know what you are referring to.

If you want my help, be explicit.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-20**:
For "the way it was before", check the 2nd edit in the question, that's the response I'm getting for `sudo apt update`.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-20**:
`stf.if.usp.br` is just the server I'm downloading from, the best one for my location.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-20**:
The outputs of the "cat" commands are in one of the edits the question above.

I've also added the output to the last code you've asked in "edit 2"

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-21**:
The output regarding the commands from #q325039 are added now on "edit 6", just tried that now and the response is still very similar to the one in "edit 2" (the first time I've removed the key and installed with the new one".
The output from `apt-key list` is in the same edit, and there is an UID of Open Robotics (and the ROS address).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-21**:
I don't see an "edit 6".

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-21**:
It's there, just below "Edit 5". I don't know if moderators need to approve, or something like that, I'm new to the forum, but if I could send you a print screen, I'd send, it's appearing normally here to me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-21**:
I see it now.

I must say at this point I'm unsure as to what is happening: you appear to have the correct key in `apt`s keyring.

You wrote you are behind a proxy before. Did you restore the proxy's configuration as well?

Can you download the release file manually? So does this work:

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:
You could try and see whether the command provided by @nickzherdev in #q325039 works:

```
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

I'm not sure what that does differently, but it could work.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-22**:
I've tried the installation procedure with and without a proxy, and the outputs didn't change at all, I believe that's not the issue.
I've tried also donwloading the release file manually, the outuput is in "Edit 7" in my question, it appears to have downloaded, but the other commands are still not working.
And my terminal didn't even recognize `sudo launchpad-getkeys`, it says "command not found".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:
You may need to install it first. See [How to Automatically Import Missing GPG Keys in Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/72934/how-to-automatically-import-missing-gpg-keys-in-ubuntu/) for one way to install it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:\

> I've tried also donwloading the release file manually, the outuput is in "Edit 7" in my question, it appears to have downloaded,

did you check the contents?

> but the other commands are still not working.

I did not expect them to.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-22**:
What do you mean by "chekc the contents". Can you be more specific?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:
Well, did it look like the file was ok? Was it corrupted in any way? Anything to indicate problems during transmission? Etc.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-22**:
Apparently, there were no problems with the file, it was OK.

**Comment by [AlexRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/41956/alexribeiro/) on 2019-06-22**:
And, about the "launchpad-getkeys", I couldn't install, the errors that happened were extremely similar to the one I'm getting with ROS Melodic... It's appearing to be very likely that it's a bigger problem im my Ubuntu...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:
Have you tried the live-usb / install-usb already?